# How to secure access to API Gateway using Cognito & make it accessible only through CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

A use case that I currently have to set up with AWS has several constraints:

- I have to use a Cognito User Pool as an authorizer with my API resources (so far no problem)
- I also have to make the API only accessible through a CloudFront distribution (like an OAI for an S3 bucket)

To set up this use case, I was going to use a Lambda@Edge attached to the CloudFront to generate a request signature (SignV4), on the other hand I was going to use a Custom Authorizer, which would verify the signature of the request generated with the Lambda@Edge in addition to verifying the authentication with Cognito.

Only I don't know exactly how to do it, especially how to use Cognito in a custom authorizer (AWS SDK).
What do you think of this solution?

The only other solution I found is [this one](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-2/), but to me it should not be the usage for an API key, and the signed request solution seems, to my opinion, a better choice.

Do you know a better one?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you